# How to get rid of belly fat for a Skinny-Fat person

Tags: exercise, cardio, bellyfat, crunches

I am a skinny person with 179cm height and 64KG (141 Pound) however I've a lot fat around my belly and this often prevents me wearing T-shirts. The belly fat gives a very weird shape to my body.

To get rid of this belly fat I started Running and 1000 (2 sets)Jumping Rope (skipping) along with gym, but at the end of 2 months I end up loosing 4KG (68 to 64) but even though there was no visible change in my belly fat which made me appear even bad.

I wonder what is the best way to reduce belly fat for me without loosing much of the other fat and at the same time increase muscles mass? Will crunches do a trick or I should cardio exercise and first loose all fat and then start gaining the muscles mass?

Comment: Long story short, you can't choose where to lose fat. Either you lose it all over, or not at all. And please use the search function. This question probably has 50 duplicates here.

Answer (score 0):

You can find many writings about losing belly fat in a week but in reality body start to shrink fat cell size (lose fat) depending where it gained first. Since you didn't gain all the weight in a week it will take some time to lose it. That is why, first be patient and stick with your diet and exercise regularly. Do not google it, consult your physician and dietitian and follow their recommendations. To do list is somewhat long but as the time passes it will turn into your life style. At least give yourself 6 months to see the changes. Be patient and you will get rid off you belly fat for sure.